# ¿Por qué se necesita "que" en "no hará falta que le recuerde *que* velaré por..."?

Tags: conjunciones

[image: ....le recuerde....**que** velaré por...]

Hola a todos, me cuesta mucho entender los usos de "que".

En la foto, la frase

> no hará falta que le recuerde, doctor Cartre - dijo Jared a Sam - que velaré por...

Alguien me dijo que si se elimina el "que" antes de "velaré por" y se reformula como *-No hará falta que le recuerde, doctor Carter - dijo Jaré a Sam - Velaré por que...*, los significados son el mismo, pero pierde algún sentido...

Yo no entiendo. 
Si lo traduzco al inglés, es:

> It will not be necessary that I remind you (that) I will make sure.....

El "that" puede ser obviado.

Mi duda es por qué el "que" es necesario.

Comment: En ese contexto es similar a un "that", pero en español no es opcional.

Comment: El idioma español está lleno de *que* en la mayoría de sus afirmaciones. Generalmente, conecta cláusulas para mantener la coherencia y cohesión de estas afirmaciones. El caso del inglés es distinto, pues ellos no necesitan añadir *that* a cada rato para armas las afirmaciones subordinadas, como en expresiones del estilo *I think I'll go*, pues nosotros no diríamos *Creo iré*. En pocas palabras, sí es una necesidad. — Se cuentan con los dedos las veces en que dispensamos esta conjunción en español.

Comment: Hola Cardenza, así como está tu publicación, es poco práctico para referenciar partes del libro. Mi recomendación es la de copiar lo necesario (no son muchas líneas) y eliminar la fotografía.

Answer (score 3):

La conjunción *que* sirve, entre otras cosas, para introducir complementos directos, sustituibles por *eso*:

> «¡Yo no quiero [*que* te vayas]!» ~ «¡Yo no quiero [eso]!»

Algunos verbos admiten que la conjunción se omita, sobre todo en contextos formales. Estos son, según el [DPD](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=2VAvJgr6tD6bMa8swW), apartado 2.1.2, los verbos de ruego, temor o, en menor medida, opinión:

> «Le rogué • me permitiera acompañarla hasta la entrada»
>   «Ya me temo • no termine nunca [esta guerra]»
>   «El comunicado [...] eriza el cabello y supongo • habrá espantado al ministro Belloch»

Aunque no es incorrecto eliminar la conjunción *que* con estos verbos, el DPD recomienda mantenerla. En los ejemplos anteriores, se debería colocar donde están los puntos (•).

En tu caso, la conjunción no es omisible.

Comment: Hallo horrible la omisión de esta conjunción cuando invoca al subjuntivo. ¿Se usa allá en España? Acá con suerte se usan *ojalá vaya / espero vaya* con omisión del *que.*

Comment: @Ustanak Solo en contextos muy formales, y ni siquiera entonces me suena bien omitirla. Yo solo lo he oído de forma más o menos consistente con el verbo "rogar" en comunicados por escrito, como en el ejemplo que da el DPD: «Le rogamos de la manera más atenta se sirva publicar la siguiente carta».

Comment: El ejemplo que expones me suena en realidad. Lo había oído antes, en ámbitos legales. Ahí tiene sentido la omisión en aspectos formales como lo mencionabas. Pensé que se usaba a nivel regional, por eso la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

El "que" no es obligatorio cuando es el encabezado de una trata de una Proposición Incluida Sustantiva (P.I.S, también llamada Proposición Subordinada Sustantiva), mientras que en las Proposiciones Incluidas Adjetivas (P.I.A) y en las Proposiciones Incluidas Adverbiales (P.I.Adv) lo es.

Te recomiendo darle un vistazo a este [link](https://www.google.com.ar/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjMw_6bzpHOAhVEDJAKHUAlAGMQFggiMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpostgradofadecs.uncoma.edu.ar%2Fimages%2FProposiciones_incluidas.doc&usg=AFQjCNH5Q7MVEBI2HRyoQ5Wq2Oyt5E8WJw) (es el link para la descarga de un archivo .doc de una Universidad Nacional de Argentina)

Espero que te sirva

Edit: En este [link](http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Conjunci%C3%B3n%20que%20-%20omisi%C3%B3n.htm) se detalla exactamente con qué verbos se puede o no hacer omisión de la conjunción "que"

Comment: No estoy de acuerdo con que no sea obligatorio. Sacando ejemplos del Word que mencionas, el *que* es obligatorio y omitirlo resulta en frases sin sentido: "Quiero me escribas", "estoy convencido de vi a tu cuñada".

Comment: En el primer caso tienes totalmente la razón. Con respecto a la segunda oración, me confundí en la respuesta y quise referirme a cuando él encabezado es solamente "que". Aun así, encontré un link el cual tiene casos particulares en los cuales se admite omisión http://hispanoteca.eu/gram%C3%A1ticas/Gram%C3%A1tica%20espa%C3%B1ola/Conjunci%C3%B3n%20que%20-%20omisi%C3%B3n.htm

Comment: En el enlace que incluíste, ¿se añaden los tecnicismos que mencionaste en tu respuesta? De no ser así, podrías añadir información respecto de ello, pues así como luce la respuesta, se halla un poco vacía.

Comment: @Ustanak gracias, ahí agregué a la respuesta la información del link